# How to insert character ('-") every time my string changes from text to number and vice versa?

Tags: python, pandas, series

This is an example of a bigger dataframe. Imagine I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["4SSS50FX","2TT1897FA"],
                   "VALUE":[13, 56]})

df
Out[2]: 
          ID  VALUE
0   4SSS50FX     13
1  2TT1897FA     56
```

I would like to insert "-" in the strings from df["ID"] everytime it changes from number to text and from text to number. So the output should be like:

```
          ID  VALUE
0   4-SSS-50-FX     13
1  2-TT-1897-FA     56
```

I could create specific conditions for each case, but I would like to automate it for all the samples. Anyone could help me?

Comment: You have two problems: adding the hyphens to a string and doing it across a column in a DataFrame. Which are you asking about?

Comment: hi @nicomp I am asking how to add the hyphens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace(r'(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)', '-')
```

The regexp matches an empty string that's either preceded by a digit and followed by a letter, or vice versa. This empty string is then replaced with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex.

```
>>> df['ID'].str.replace('(\d+(?=\D)|\D+(?=\d))', r'\1-', regex=True)
0     4-SSS-50-FX
1    2-TT-1897-FA
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

`\d+(?=\D)` means digits followed by non-digit.
`\D+(?=\d))` means non-digits followed by digit.

Either of those are replaced with themselves plus a `-` character.